# Linear Optimization: Unique solutions are extremal points

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I need to show that given a convex set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $\overline{x} \in K$ the following holds:

If $\overline{x}$ is a unique solution to the $LP$

$\min_{x \in K} \ c^Tx$

then $\overline{x}$ is an extremal point.

We defined an extremal point $a$ as a point in $K$ such that every convex combination in $K$ with $a = \lambda*b + (1-\lambda)*c$ has the property $\lambda = 1$ or $(1-\lambda) = 1$ $\forall \ a,b \in K \ with \ a \ne b$).

I tried doing this with a proof by contradiction, i.e.: assuming there was a $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $\overline{x} = \lambda*b + (1-\lambda)*c$ for some $b,c \in K$, but I don't see how I could go on with this approach.

Could you give me any hints?

Comment: Just plug the points $x=t a+(1-t)b$ (changed your names because there is already a $c$ in the LP) into $c^Tx=t(c^Ta)+(1-t)c^Tb=c^Tb+t(c^Ta-c^Tb)$. If $c^Ta-c^Tb\neq 0$ then increasing or decreasing $t$ you get a better value than at $t=\lambda$. If $c^Ta-c^Tb=0$ then at all the points in the interval from $a$ to $b$ you get the same value as at $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this solves it.

Comment: Is $c \in K$ in this problem?